# ResizeImage Processor Missing in NiFi 1.14

Tags: apache-nifi

Title states the entire question, but I am confused as to why the ResizeImage processor is not preset in NiFi version 1.14. From what I can tell, it was present in 1.9 (earlier release), and I do not see anything in the migration notes that discuss the removal of this processor.

I am not certain how to proceed in this instance as I need this processor or something similar. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `nifi-media-nar` was removed from the convenience binaries under [NIFI-6604](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-6604) to reduce the size of the binaries to conform to Apache Software Foundation rules. However it is still built and published as part of the Apache NiFi release, you can find it here: [nifi-media-nar-1.14.0.nar](https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/releases/org/apache/nifi/nifi-media-nar/1.14.0/nifi-media-nar-1.14.0.nar)

Comment: Marked as the answer. Thank you for providing me the file itself. I was looking through the github repo, but was focused on ResizeImage and not Media. Thanks.